# Backbone.js adding to Collection

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

In Backbone, I have a collection which is populated with some JSON data which looks like below.

```
[
{
    "test1": {
        "fistName": "test",
        "lastName": "example"
    },
    "test2": {
        "fistName": "test",
        "lastName": "example"
    }
},
{
    "test1": {
        "fistName": "test",
        "fistName": "example"
    },
    "test2": {
        "fistName": "test",
        "fistName": "example"
    }
},
```

]

Currently im trying to add a new model to the collection holding data like the above.

This is the model.

```
Test = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults : {
        test1: {
            firstName: null,
            lastName: null
        },
        test2: {
            firstName: null,
            lastName: null
        }
    },
```

});

Below is what I am trying

```
var test = new Test({test1: {firstName: $("#test1 option:selected").val(), score: $("#test1lastName").val()}}, {test2: {firstName: $("#test2 option:selected").val(), score: $("#test2lastName").val()}});

myCollection.add(test);
```

However doing this only populates test1 data and not test2 data. What would be the correct way to add both test1 and test2 data into the model, which could then be added to the collection.

Thanks

UPDATE

Just to clarify, test 1 and 2 are not separate objects, they are relevant to each other and need to be in the same model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit, depending on how your model is defined, if you format it as below you might able to debug a little better.

```
var test = new TFS.Test({
    test1: {
        firstName: $("#test1 option:selected").val(),,
        lastName: '', // code for last name? 
        score: $("#test1lastName").val()
    },
    test2: {
        firstName: $("#test2 option:selected").val(),
        lastName: '', 
        score: $("#test2lastName").val()
    }
});

myCollection.add(test);
```

I might be able to offer you a little more help if you give a better view of the entire action/process - i.e. what is triggering the creation of these models? Could there be a problem with jQuery, and your document not being ready?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, No im just trying to add one object as test1 and test2 a relevant to each other and need to be in the same model

Comment: Nothing wrong really with the model, where is the code where you create the new model, and what does your html look like....?